# Get Feedback from Move Base if goal is reachable

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, action-client, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running the move base navigation package (Local planner DWA, global planner NavfnROS).
The problem is, I would like to determine whenever the goal is not reachable.
Unfortunately, the documentation of the actions is currently down:
http://docs.ros.org/api/move_base_msgs/html/msg/MoveBaseActionFeedback.html

I suspect the information to be available via the topics

> /move_base/feedback
> /move_base/status
> /move_base/result

Also using the action server:

```
move_base_client_.sendGoal(goal);
actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState status=move_base_client_.getState();
```

I could not find any indicator that if the goal is reachable in the status message.

Do you have any idea how to get a notification when the goal is not reachable?
Thanks a lot!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329264/get-feedback-from-move-base-if-goal-is-reachable/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to modify and compile your own version of NavfnROS.
Clone the navigation stack from github and search for

> NavfnROS::getPlanFromPotential

Then look for the snippet below and modify it to publish your feedback!

```
if(!costmap_->worldToMap(wx, wy, mx, my)){
  //publish the feedback from here!
  ROS_WARN_THROTTLE(1.0, "The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.");
  return false;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ashutosh08](https://answers.ros.org/users/44302/ashutosh08/) with karma: 28 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2019-07-29**:
Hi, thanks a lot for your help.
I have tried your idea with:

```
std_msgs::Bool flag_goal_not_reachable;
flag_goal_not_reachable.data=false;
if(!costmap_->worldToMap(wx, wy, mx, my)){
  flag_goal_not_reachable.data=true;
  pub_target_not_reachable_.publish(flag_goal_not_reachable);
  ROS_WARN_THROTTLE(1.0, "The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.");
  return false;
}
pub_target_not_reachable_.publish(flag_goal_not_reachable);
```

Unfortunately, I in my tests this does not work (publish "True" when goal is unreachable).
My problem is that my robot gets stuck in corners:
The goal is between the robot's base and the wall, while the footprint of the robot inhibits collides with the wall an inhibits the robot to move further. So the goal is not reached?!

I have the feeling that the footprint may not be considered in the "!costmap_->worldToMap(wx, wy, mx, my)" routine? Do you have any recommendation?